# removing unicode characters from data frame in r

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have a large data frame which contains farsi characters I import it in r with this code:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "persian")
dt <- read.csv("data.csv",encoding="UTF-8")
```

and my dt is like this:

```
id         title
3376971    چوب شور آلبينا شيرين عسل <U+06F3><U+06F0> گرمي
3376989    ويفر رنگارنگ مينو <U+06F1><U+06F4>.<U+06F5> گرمي
3376990    کوکي مينو <U+06F3><U+06F0> گرمي
3376991    بيسکويت هاي باي شيرين عسل <U+06F3><U+06F8> گرمي
3376992    شکلات توريستي آناتا <U+06F2><U+06F8> گرمي
3376993    اسنک مغزدار شکلاتي شونيز <U+06F1><U+06F7> گرمي
3376994    شکلات فندقي آناتا <U+06F1><U+06F8> گرمي
3376995    نان روغني شيرين عسل <U+06F5><U+06F0> گرمي
3376996    بيسکويت هاي باي شيرين عسل <U+06F5><U+06F7> گرمي
```

There are some unicode which I'd like to remove, I have tried:

```
dt<- cbind.data.frame(dt$id,gsub("<.+>", "", dt$title)
dt<- cbind.data.frame(dt$id,gsub("\\S+\\s+|-", "", dt$title)
dt<- cbind.data.frame(dt$id,gsub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*", "", dt$title)
dt<- cbind.data.frame(dt$id,gsub("\\<U[^\\>]*\\>", "", dt$title)  
dt<- cbind.data.frame(dt$id,gsub(""▼|▲"", "", dt$title)
```

but non of them works

I also tried this:

```
dt$title<-gsub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*", "", dt$title)
```

but I got this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, title, value = character(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 66366
```

Comment: try ```transform(title = stringi::stri_trans_general(title, "latin-ascii"))```

Comment: The string probably doesn't actually contain those bracketed elements like `<U+06F3>`, those are just unicode characters that R doesn't know how to display so it shows you the code instead. If you write the dataframe to a CSV, what do you see?

Comment: @Marius, i tried  `write.csv`  I see exactly dt as It's shown in  the question

Comment: @ julien, I tried it but it doesnt work I got this error:    `Error in data.frame(`_data`) : argument "_data" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @Marius, @julien, I noticed that in the R console the Unicode are shown differnently: ` چوب شور آلبینا شیرین عسل ۳۰ گرمی  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in R console my data are shown like this:

```
چوب شور آلبینا شیرین عسل ۳۰ گرمی
```

and the Unicode has been shown like Persian numbers and I tried this and it worked:

```
dt$title<-gsub("[۰-۹]+", "", dt$title)
```